# Python Integer and String Using

Tags: python

```
for size in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    result = 0
    print("size=" + str(size))
    for element in range(size):
        result = result + element
        print(" adding " + str(element)+", result so far=" + str(result))
    print("Done. size=" + str(size) + " result=" + str(result))
print("All done!")
```

I wonder why we use the `str()` function on `size` and `result` in the 7th line. I know we can't use integer and string in a single print function, but if the rule is like this, why isn't there any problem in this code (about integer + string rule)?

```
x=18
print("Hello , I am" , x , "years old.")
```

We use integer and string in a single line don't we ?

Comment: In the first code, you print a string. 

In the second code you print a tuple.

Comment: @C.Dlp - That's only in Python 2, and it looks like the OP is using Python 3, in which case it's a function call with multiple arguments rather than a statement working with a single tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the order things are run:

```
"Done. size=" + str(size) + " result=" + str(result)
```

has to be done first, *before* the `print` function is called.  The `print` function just gets the single joined string - it has no idea that a `+` was used to construct it.

In this case:

```
print("Hello , I am" , x , "years old.")
```

the `print` function gets all 4 arguments (actually, a 4 element tuple) and can now work its magic on converting each one to a string itself (see *Unnecessary detail* below).

By the way, if you object to having to use `str()` then there are other ways of formatting the string to print.  The following lines all produce the same output:

```
print("Done. size=" + str(size) + " result=" + str(result))
print("Done. size=%d result=%d" % (size, result))
print("Done. size={} result={}".format(size, result))
print(f"Done. size={size:} result={result:}")
```

The last one `f" "` requires Python 3.6 or later.

Unnecessary detail:

The conversion to `str()` in the `print()` function is actually done (in the C implementation) by the python API call `PyFile_WriteObject()` using the flag `Py_PRINT_RAW`.   If `Py_PRINT_RAW` is given, the str() of the object is written.

Comment: print("Done. size=" ,size," result=",result) It also worked.Can we concatenate str and int objects with comma ?

Comment: It is not concatenating objects with the comma. Print just receives a few arguments, transform each of them to strings and later concatenates them.

Comment: @Gingerbread: no.  A comma is not an operator in python, and it would be hellishly confusing if it was.  The `print` function reads each argument and performs a `str()` on it itself.   What's wrong with the mechanisms I showed you?

Answer (score 1):

Just because two references appear together in a single line doesn't mean they're being concatenated. If the first example, you are concatenating strings (which is why they all have to be strings) and sending them to the `print` function. In the second example, you are sending multiple arguments to the `print` function, which will print each one. The `print` function can handle an arbitrary number of arguments, which don't necessarily have to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The plus (`+`) operator is not able to add strings and numbers. That's why you need to use `str()`.

If you try:

```
"hello" + 2
```

you will get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

When using `print(a, "b", c, d)` you are passing multiple arguments and there is not need for concatenation. Each argument is transformed to a string before printing.