# Why does Python print handle non types but string not?

Tags: python, string, printing

Why does python handle this

```
a = None
b = 'blub' 
print(a)
print(b)
```

but not

```
print(a + ' ' + b)
```

It gives: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Why doesn't it just convert it to None as in the above case? And how could I get such behaviour?

Comment: The error tells exactly what is not working: "unsupported operand type(s) for +". Issue is with plus operator not print.

Comment: I understand the error and I know how to fix it. My question is why it is this way.

Comment: @Hakaishin: because explicit is better than implicit. Convert your `None` value to a string first: `str(a) + ..`. Or use string formatting.

Comment: In general, `+` does not try to guess whether `a + b` should convert `a` to `b`'s type, or convert `b` to `a`'s type.

Comment: @Hakaishin your question explicitly mentioned print while print has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Very similar to recent question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171202/python-integer-and-string-using) (can't mark as duplicate because there are no upvoted or accepted answers).

Comment: It has to do with print. Print decides to convert the None type to the string None or atleast that's what it prints. So I was wondering why doesn't + do the same. But I see it comes from the whole explicit is better the implicit. That reason together with @moses koledoye's answer would be the perfect answer I was looking for. A reason and another simpler way to achieve what I wanted. calling str(a) seems cumbersom, just adding the commas looks much better.

Comment: Please use "string interpolation", there are several forms to choose from from `%s` to f-strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concat was not designed to auto-coerce other types into strings on the fly, because *explicit is better than implicit*. You can use string formatting for that:

```
print('{} {} {}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Or just pass the parameters directly to `print`:

```
print(a, b, c)
```

You could also explicitly convert the other types to strings. And do the concat.

Comment: Ah perfect, both solutions were what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah, just proof of concept.

Comment: Had to wait a minimum amount of time :)

Comment: Why did you remove the part "because 'the view that' explicit is better than implicit" ? That's definitely not true. I mean why would there even be such a thing like implicit conversion if it's never better? Implicit things have their fair use and claiming explicit is better than implicit is just wrong. @MosesKoledoye

Comment: @Hakaishin I didn't remove it. The statement was taken from the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 2):

Because a and c are not strings, you should try :

```
print(str(a) + ' ' + b + ' ' + str(c))
```

The problem isn't "print", but the concatenation of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

As to why, look at the case of `36 + 'abc'`  Should this convert `36` to a string and concatenate the strings, or should it convert `abc` to a numeric value and add the numbers?  There's no right answer, and so Python doesn't guess unless it has specific rules about those two types.

Comment: To me it seems obvious it should be converted to a string. Like 90% of the time I don't want the string as a numeric value. And in the rare case I want it as a numeric value I will be really aware of it and convert it explicitly. To me it makes more sense Implicit for stuff that happens often explicit for rare cases.

Comment: @Hakaishin - Why should it be converted to a string? If `36 + 'abc'` is implicitly converted, it should obviously evaluate to 2784. :P In the face of ambiguity like this, Python prefers not to guess.

Comment: As I explained because that is what people want in 90% of the cases. I understand that you can't formally prefer one over the other, but there is a real world where real people do things. This is the same kind of weird pythonism that prevents i++ being in python.

Comment: I think `36 + '13'` would be a stronger example. Perl for example actually does evaluate that to 49.